# AutoFixture with "weak" types

Tags: xunit, autofixture

I love [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture), but have run into a bit of very repetitive "arrange" code that I feel like it should be able to handle - somehow.

Here is my scenario, illustrated using implementations of `IInterceptor` from [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/).

First the systems under test:

```cs
public class InterceptorA : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation context)
    {
        object proxy = context.Proxy;
        object returnValue = context.ReturnValue;
        // Do something with proxy and returnValue
    }
}

public class InterceptorB : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation context)
    {
        object returnValue = context.ReturnValue;
        // Do something with different returnValue
    }
}
```

Now for a few simple tests which leverage the data theories support for [xUnit](http://xunit.codeplex.com/):

```cs
public class InterceptorATests
{
    [Theory, CustomAutoData]
    public void TestA1(InterceptorA sut, IInvocation context)
    {
        Mock.Get(context).Setup(c => c.Proxy).Returns("a");
        Mock.Get(context).Setup(c => c.ReturnValue).Returns("b");

        sut.Intercept(context);
        // assert
    }
}

public class InterceptorBTests
{
    [Theory, CustomAutoData]
    public void TestB1(InterceptorB sut, IInvocation context)
    {
        Mock.Get(context).Setup(c => c.ReturnValue).Returns("z");
        sut.Intercept(context);
        // assert
    }
}
```

My `CustomAutoData` attribute does in fact customize AutoFixture so that the injected instances of `IInvocation` are *mostly* configured properly, but since every `IInterceptor` implementation expects completely different types for the `Proxy` and `ReturnValue` properties, each test has to set those on their own. (Thus the `Mock.Get(context).Setup(...)` calls.)

This is okay, except that every test in `InterceptorATests` must repeat the same few lines of arrangement, as well as every test in `InterceptorBTests`.

Is there a way to cleanly remove the repetitive `Mock.Get(...)` calls? Is there a good way to access the `IFixture` instance for a given test class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are tons of things you can do - depending on exactly *what* it is that you really want to test.

First of all I would like to point out that much of the trouble in this particular question originates in the extremely weakly typed API of IInvocation, as well as the fact that Moq doesn't implement properties as we normally implement properties.

**Don't setup stubs if you don't need them**

First of all, you don't *have* to setup return values for the Proxy and ReturnValue properties if you don't need them.

The way AutoFixture.AutoMoq sets up `Mock<T>` instances is that it always sets `DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock`. Since the return type of both properties is `object` and `object` has a default constructor, you will automatically get an object (actually, an `ObjectProxy`) back.

In other words, these tests also pass:

```
[Theory, CustomAutoData]
public void TestA2(InterceptorA sut, IInvocation context)
{
    sut.Intercept(context);
    // assert
}

[Theory, CustomAutoData]
public void TestB2(InterceptorB sut, IInvocation context)
{
    sut.Intercept(context);
    // assert
}
```

**Directly assign ReturnValue**

For the rest of my answer, I'm going to assume that you actually need to assign and/or read the property values in your tests.

First of all, you can cut down on the heavy Moq syntax by assigning the ReturnValue directly:

```
[Theory, Custom3AutoData]
public void TestA3(InterceptorA sut, IInvocation context)
{
    context.ReturnValue = "b";

    sut.Intercept(context);
    // assert
    Assert.Equal("b", context.ReturnValue);
}

[Theory, Custom3AutoData]
public void TestB3(InterceptorB sut, IInvocation context)
{
    context.ReturnValue = "z";

    sut.Intercept(context);
    // assert
    Assert.Equal("z", context.ReturnValue);
}
```

However, it only works for `ReturnValue` since it's a writable property. It doesn't work with the `Proxy` property because it's read-only (it's not going to compile).

In order to make this work, you must instruct Moq to treat `IInvocation` properties as 'real' properties:

```
public class Customization3 : CompositeCustomization
{
    public Customization3()
        : base(
            new RealPropertiesOnInvocation(),
            new AutoMoqCustomization())
    {
    }

    private class RealPropertiesOnInvocation : ICustomization
    {
        public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
        {
            fixture.Register<Mock<IInvocation>>(() =>
                {
                    var td = new Mock<IInvocation>();
                    td.DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock;
                    td.SetupAllProperties();
                    return td;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the call to `SetupAllProperties`.

This works because AutoFixture.AutoMoq works by relaying all requests for interfaces to a request for a Mock of that interface - i.e. a request for `IInvocation` is converted to a request for `Mock<IInvocation>`.

**Don't set the test values; read them back**

In the end, you should ask yourself: Do I really need to assign specific values (such as "a", "b" and "z") to these properties. Couldn't I just let AutoFixture create the required values? And if I do that, do I need to explicitly assign them? Couldn't I just read back the assigned value instead?

This is possibly with a little trick I call *Signal Types*. A Signal Type is a class that signals a particular *role* of a value.

Introduce a signal type for each property:

```
public class InvocationReturnValue
{
    private readonly object value;

    public InvocationReturnValue(object value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
    }
}

public class InvocationProxy
{
    private readonly object value;

    public InvocationProxy(object value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
    }
}
```

(If you require the values to always be strings, you can change the constructor signature to require a `string` instead of an `object`.)

Freeze the Signal Types you care about so that you know the same instance is going to be reused when the IInvocation instance is configured:

```
[Theory, Custom4AutoData]
public void TestA4(
    InterceptorA sut,
    [Frozen]InvocationProxy proxy,
    [Frozen]InvocationReturnValue returnValue,
    IInvocation context)
{
    sut.Intercept(context);
    // assert
    Assert.Equal(proxy.Value, context.Proxy);
    Assert.Equal(returnValue.Value, context.ReturnValue);
}

[Theory, Custom4AutoData]
public void TestB4(
    InterceptorB sut,
    [Frozen]InvocationReturnValue returnValue,
    IInvocation context)
{
    sut.Intercept(context);
    // assert
    Assert.Equal(returnValue.Value, context.ReturnValue);
}
```

The beauty of this approach is that in those test cases where you don't care about the `ReturnValue` or `Proxy` you can just omit those method arguments.

The corresponding Customization is an expansion of the previous:

```
public class Customization4 : CompositeCustomization
{
    public Customization4()
        : base(
            new RelayedPropertiesOnInvocation(),
            new AutoMoqCustomization())
    {
    }

    private class RelayedPropertiesOnInvocation : ICustomization
    {
        public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
        {
            fixture.Register<Mock<IInvocation>>(() =>
                {
                    var td = new Mock<IInvocation>();
                    td.DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock;
                    td.SetupAllProperties();

                    td.Object.ReturnValue = 
                        fixture.CreateAnonymous<InvocationReturnValue>().Value;
                    td.Setup(i => i.Proxy).Returns(
                        fixture.CreateAnonymous<InvocationProxy>().Value);

                    return td;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the that value for each property is assigned by asking the IFixture instance to create a new instance of the corresponding Signal Type and then unwrapping its value.

This approach can be generalized, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Mark. I have to admit it wasn't what I was hoping for, and I've used Signal Types in the past, but it was very informative and it's what I have to go off of right now. Keep up the great work on AutoFixture!

Comment: What were you hoping for? I looked through your proposed solution, and while I realize that it's a PoC, I don't understand how it makes anything better.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up dropping down a level to xUnit's extensibility points to solve this problem - inspired by the Signal Type pattern mentioned in Mark's answer.

Now my test's have an additional attribute: `Signal`.

```cs
public class InterceptorATests
{
    [Theory, CustomAutoData]
    public void TestA1(InterceptorA sut, [Signal(typeof(SpecialContext))] IInvocation context)
    {
        // no more repetitive arrangement!
        sut.Intercept(context);
        // assert
    }
}
```

The `SignalAttribute` class is very simple:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SignalAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ISignalType SignalType { get; set; }

    public SignalAttribute(Type customization)
    {
        SignalType = (ISignalType)Activator.CreateInstance(customization);
    }
}
```

The real magic comes in my newly updated `CustomAutoData` class:

```cs
public class CustomAutoDataAttribute: AutoDataAttribute
{
    public CustomAutoDataAttribute() : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodUnderTest, Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
        Type input = null;
        ISignalType signalType = null;

        foreach (var parameter in methodUnderTest.GetParameters())
        {
            var attribute = parameter.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(SignalAttribute)) as SignalAttribute;

            if (attribute == null)
                continue;

            input = parameter.ParameterType;
            signalType = attribute.SignalType;

            break;
            // this proof of concept only supports one parameter at a time
        }

        var result = base.GetData(methodUnderTest, parameterTypes);

        if (input == null)
            return result;

        int index = Array.IndexOf(parameterTypes, input);

        foreach (var objectSet in result)
        {
            signalType.Customize(objectSet[index]);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Finally, I just create my `SpecialContext`. I create it as a nested class in `InterceptorATests`, but it could live anywhere:

```cs
public class SpecialContext : ISignalType
{
    public void Customize(object obj)
    {
        var input = (IInvocation)obj;
        Mock.Get(input).Setup(i => i.Proxy).Returns("a");
        Mock.Get(input).Setup(i => i.ReturnValue).Returns("b");
    }
}
```

This allows me to effectively hook in after AutoFixture has done *most* of the work creating an `IInvocation`, but specify further customizations in one place.

NOTE: This is proof of concept code! It does not handle many scenarios properly. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Have you looked into deriving your custom, parameter-bound attribute from `Ploeh.AutoFixture.Xunit.CustomizeAttribute` instead? Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: The `[Customize]` attribute is the base class for AutoFixture.Xunit attributes such as `[Frozen]`, `[FavorArrays]`, etc.

Comment: No I have not, I was not aware of that class's existence. I'll take a look and see!

Comment: Was it your goal to move the setup of `IInvocation` to a separate class? If so, why not use a specialized `[AutoData]` and `ICustomization` pair?

Comment: I'd prefer to move the setup of `IInvocation` to a method, and may in the future.

Comment: I can't move the setup code to an `ICustomization` because a need a different customization per SUT. In this example `InterceptorA` and `InterceptorB` expect dramatically different `IInvocation` instances.

Comment: With the `ISignalType` approach outlined above, you'd *also* need to define a class implementing this interface per SUT. How is this better than defining a class implementing `ICustomization` per SUT?