# NSubstitute and AutoFixture issue with Received

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture, nsubstitute

I have problem with `Received()` method from NSubsitute.

My test class:

```
private readonly IFixture _fixture;

    public NotificationsCenterTests()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture();
        _fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior());
        _fixture.Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());
    }
```

This method works good:

```
[Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
    public void Send_NotificationIsNotNull_NotificationShouldBeSendAndSaved(
        IDocumentDbRepository<NotificationDocument> repository,
        Notification notification
        )
    {
        // Arrange
        var sender = Substitute.For<INotificationSender>();

        var notificationsCenter = new NotificationsCenter(
            sender, repository);
        // Act
        Func<Task> action = async () => await notificationsCenter.SendAsync(notification);

        // Assert
        action.Invoke();
        sender.Received(1).Send(Arg.Any<Notification>());
    }
```

And this sends error:

```
[Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
    public void Send_NotificationIsNotNull_NotificationShouldBeSendAndSaved2(
        INotificationSender sender,
        IDocumentDbRepository<NotificationDocument> repository,
        NotificationsCenter notificationsCenter,
        Notification notification
        )
    {
        // Act
        Func<Task> action = async () => await notificationsCenter.SendAsync(notification);

        // Assert
        action.Invoke();
        sender.Received(1).Send(Arg.Any<Notification>());
    }
```

It my autonsubsisute attribute:

```
internal class AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture()
            .Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

And the error in method 2 is:

```
NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException : Expected to receive exactly 1 call matching:
    Send(any Notification)
Actually received no matching calls.
```

What is going on? I want do some code with TDD but I have stopped at this little issue. And I dont have idea what is wrong with the second code.

Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, `NotificationsCenter` is created with *different* instances for `repository` and `sender`.

Although `repository` and `sender` are declared before the `NotificationsCenter` argument, that doesn't mean that the same instance is reused.

You need to use the `[Frozen]` attribute for this, as shown in the following resources:

- http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14709809/467754
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13962541/467754
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16614828/467754